# what happens after read is called for a Linux socket

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

What actually happens after calling read:

```
n = read(fd, buf, try_read_size);
```

here fd is a TCP socket descriptor. buf is the buffer. try_read_size is the number of bytes that the program tries to read.

I guess this may finally invokes a system call to the kernel. But could anyone provide some details? say the source code implementation in glibc or kernel source?

Comment: kernel details are way too complex for a short SO answer. and BTW why don't you check it yourself?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I tried but totally got lost. Any direction or suggestion to get the details? I will highly appreciate it.

Comment: Read fs/read_write.c from the linux kernel source and see what's happening.

Comment: that's just the generic read function, isn't it? TCP related stuff must be in net/ somewhere.

Comment: @strkol Thanks! I find "SYSCALL_DEFINE3(read, unsigned int, fd, char __user *, buf, size_t, count)" ( http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.2/fs/read_write.c#L460 ). Diving into the code from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a high-level perspective, this is what happens:

- A wrapper function provided by glibc is called
- The wrapper function puts the parameters passed on the stack into registers and sets the syscall number in the register dedicated for that purpose (e.g. EAX on x86)
- The wrapper function executes a trap or equivalent instruction (e.g. SYSENTER)
- The CPU switches to ring0, and the trap handler is invoked
- The trap handler checks the syscall number for validity and looks it up in a jump table to kernel functions
- The respective kernel function checks whether arguments are valid (e.g. the range `buf` to `buf+try_read_size` refers to accessible memory pages, `fd` is really a file descriptor). If something is amiss, a negative error code (e.g. -EFAULT) is generated, the cpu is switched back to user mode and the call returns to the wrapper.
- Another function is called depending on the file descriptor's type (in your case a socket, but one could read from a block device or a `proc` entry or something more exotic)
- The socket's input buffer is checked:

  - If there is some data in the buffer, `min(available, try_read_size)` is copied to `buf`, the amount is written to the return code register (EAX on x86), the cpu is switched back to user mode and the call returns to the wrapper.
  - If the input buffer is empty

    - If the connection has been closed, zero is written to the return code register, the cpu is switched back to user mode and the call returns to the wrapper
    - If the connection has *not* been closed

      - A negative error code (`-EAGAIN`) is written to the return code register if the socket is nonblocking, the cpu is switched back to user mode and the call returns to the wrapper.
      - The process is suspended if the socket is *not* non-blocking
- The wrapper function checks whether the return value is negative (error).

  - If positive or zero, it returns the value.
  - If negative, it sets errno to the negated value (a *positive* error is reported) and returns -1

Comment: +1, very good. If the process is suspended it blocks until at least one byte of data or a FIN is received or an error is posted on the socket, then the outermost bullet point in which this is contained restarts.